# I can't prove the Archimedes' principle in a particular case

Tags: fluid-statics, buoyancy

[image]

If I put the cylinder on the bottom i replace F2 with normal force N. But it will be at most equal to F1 plus the cylinder weigh N=F1+$\rho$gV.

So how can it get a bigger boost from the bottom to be able to float?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking about the situation where there is _no_ fluid underneath the cylinder.  This is a good question to be asking.  You've found an edge-case where Archimedes' Principle cannot be applied, and have recognized it for yourself. (see possible duplicate for actual explainations)

Comment: Have you ever tried picking up an object laying flat against the bottom of a smooth pool?

Comment: @JMac Archimedes' principle applies to this case.

Comment: @my2cts Not if there's no fluid between the bottom face of the cylinder and the bottom of the vessel.  Archimedes' Principle relies on there being pressurized fluid below the submerged object.  See for example the second paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_principle#Refinements

Comment: @JMac The weight felt by the bottom surface is the weight of the object minus the weight of the displaced fluid. Archimedes rules.

Comment: @my2cts Archimedes' principle is a consequence of the pressure gradient and how that produces a net upwards force on less dense objects; but that net upwards force **requires** a fluid below.  If the bottom face has _no_ fluid contact, and thus _no_ pressure acting on it from the fluid, the assumptions of Archimedes' principle no longer hold.  Archimedes' principle isn't some law that works on it's own, it's a handy simplification of how pressure gradients create net forces, and it does not apply when the bottom face has no fluid contact.

Comment: @Jmac Your argument is unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: @my2cts It's exactly as restrictive as the situation I've been talking about this whole time.  You responded to a comment where I made it clear I was talking about a situation with no fluid below, and how that specifically was an edge case where Archimedes' Principle does not apply.  I'm not being "unnecessarily" restrictive; I'm addressing what I believe is the specific question, which under the assumptions I was making, already had those restrictions.

Comment: @JMac This is getting a bit boring. If you are so convinced, good luck.

Comment: @my2cts I'm convinced for good reasons, which I've explained.  I'm a bit annoyed that you bothered to say I was incorrect, but cannot even support your point while I've given quite a bit of information to support mine.

Comment: @my2cts Archimedes principle relies on that bottom surface experiencing a force from the fluid. If that force is not there, then there is not even a net buoyant force upwards acting on the object from the fluid. The net force from the fluid is now downwards. Archimedes principle cannot hold here.

Comment: Thank you @JMac. Yes, that's the question, you convinced me, but i would like to hear the explanation from my2cts, because my professor too gave me the same answer, not using pascal's law but with an argument about equilibrium, that i didn't understand.

Comment: @MarioGynuu That is like seeing the proof that [angle trisection with a compass and straight edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection) is impossible but then saying "Yeah but this person had a convincing argument that it is possible, so I want to listen to that."

Comment: @MarioGynuu It's a very common _misconception_ that buoyancy still applies, because people accept the simplified version of Archimedes' principle without considering the derivation.  Your reasoning agrees with the derivation of Archimedes' principle.  In real life, just putting a cylinder against the bottom of a container likely wont prevent the fluid from getting beneath; so it will still float; but in this ideal case you're calculating, it wont.